# Regular expression for matching 2 urls cakephp route

Tags: regex, cakephp, expression

Here are the 2 examples of the urls:

/car/**2004**-audi-a**4**-**12149**

/car/**12149**

This is what I have so far:

[0-9]-[A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z]-[0-9]|[0-9]+

This only matches the parts I've emboldened above. I need to match the parts emboldened below:

/car/2004-audi-a4-**12149**

/car/**12149**

It probably makes no difference to the regex but I'm using this inside a cakephp route:

```
Router::connect(
   '/car/:id',
   array('controller' => 'cars', 'action' => 'view'),
   array(
      'pass' => array('id'),
      'id' => '[0-9]-[A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z]-[0-9]|[0-9]+'
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the last numbers of the string, you can use this.

```
\d+$
```

If I'm way off, could you try describing the pattern again?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That regex seems to match when I test it, just not when I use it inside my cakephp route for some reason. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I've never used CakePHP.  Someone else will probably be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `\d+$` is not working for you stems from this code `/car/:id`
in your route definition, you ask cake for *everything* after the slash to be matching the `\d+$`
which is not the case for `/car/2004-audi-a*4*-12149`

I would rather pass the whole `2004-audi-a*4*-12149` as a :slug to a action
and than call a regular php preg_match to extract the id using the `(\d+$)`